# Display Wrapper in lightning component salesforce

Tags: lightning

I have an apex class as below with a wrapper:

```
public class lightningController{
    public class ContactWrappertest{
    @AuraEnabled
    public boolean checked {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Contact cont {get; set;}

    public ContactWrappertest(Boolean isChecked, Contact c){
        this.checked = isChecked;
        this.cont = c;
    }
}
```

Now when i try to create a lightning component attribute as below and save it:

```
<aura:component controller="lightningController" implements="force:appHostable" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="weekWrapList" type= "lightningController.ContactWrappertest[]"/>
 </aura:component>
```

I get below error on Save:
Failed to save lightningComponent.cmp: Invalid  type: ContactWrappertest[]: Source

Can someone help me understand the issue here and try to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just started happening from latest spring 18 release or API version 42.0 I believe.

The way I resolved was to not use an inner class and instead have the inner class as its own class and then the below should save.

In your case create a class called ContactWrappertest as a separate class .

```
<aura:component controller="lightningController" implements="force:appHostable" access="global">
 <aura:attribute name="weekWrapList" type= "ContactWrappertest[]"/>
</aura:component
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. Does this mean, if we have multipe inner wrappers to handle complex logic than for that each wrapper we need to create a seperate class?

Comment: I would create them as separate classes .Did not get by complex logic ? Logic would remain on the parent class ,we are taking the inner classes out to its own class .

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203955/unable-to-set-an-inner-class-as-aura-attribute-type/204588#204588. check this out seems it was never meant to work .seems like  a bug that they fixed